# Google Real Time Notifications - Second Subscription

Tags: android, notifications, subscription

I have two apps that are going to have in-app subscriptions. I have created a Google Cloud Project, activated Pub/Sub and created a topic, linked to the project in Google Play Console, and am receiving real time notifications for the subscriptions in my app. For the second subscription app, should I:

1) Create a new Google Cloud Project, activate Pub/Sub for that project and link it in Google Play?

2) Is there a better way of getting the notifications for the second app such as perhaps using the original Google Cloud Project but creating a second topic for the second app??  I don't know if this is even possible, I am trying to keep this as straightforward and clean as possible, so want to know how most other people handle getting notifications for several different subscription apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out on my own.  You can use the same google cloud project as your first app, and you just create a second topic/subscription in Pub/Sub, and set your endpoint to the second topic for the second app.  That's it!!!